What is the difference between @coral-xyz/anchor and @project-serum/anchor?
I came across two anchor client library in nodejs. One is @coral-xyz/anchor which current version is 0.30.0 and another is @project-serum/anchor which is at 0.27.0. What is the difference between both and which is the relevant one?

use @coral-xyz/anchor, which is the current version
